# Using SWITCH() With an Aliased Column Name

Tags: sql, ms-access, switch-statement

I am using MS-Access to display an aliased column, and I am trying to combine that with a SWITCH statement. The following code works:

```
SELECT column1 & column2 AS mycol FROM tablename
```

What I would like to do is the following pseudocode:

```
SELECT SWITCH(column1 & column2 AS mycol, mycol is null, 'NONE') FROM tablename
```

Basically, there is data in both columns or there is a null in both columns. If it is null, I want it to say "NONE", otherwise concatenate the two together. How do I change the syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shou assimg the alias at the result of switch

```
SELECT SWITCH( (column1 & column2)  is  null, 'NONE') AS mycol, FROM tablename
```

Comment: That was the easiest way, thank you! I also added in [(column1 & column2)  is  not null, (column1 & column2)] to make sure to get the right behavior if it did exist.

Answer (score 0):

Though you could, you don't need a `switch`. You can use `iif`:

```
select iif(column1 is null, 'NONE', column1 & column2) as mycol
  from tablename
```

If you were to use a `switch`:

```
select switch(column1 is null, 'NONE', True, column1 & column2) as mycol
  from tablename
```